# I cannot get Mule to send an HTML formatted email

Tags: groovy, mule

I have tried all I can think of string-to-byte-array-transformer, no string-to-byte-array-transformer, and I still get the email sent in plain/text format.
Here is my gmail version when I show original message:
Subject: Why no markup?
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: **text/plain;** charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Return-Path: rufus@abc.com

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="us-ascii"/></head><body><p>An HTML paragraph</p></body></html>
```

Please shine a light on what I am doing wrong.
Thanks, Don

Below is a simple test case:

```
<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:smtp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp" xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    version="EE-3.5.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp/current/mule-smtp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/current/mule-quartz.xsd">
    <flow name="htmlemailtestFlow1" doc:name="htmlemailtestFlow1">
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="Q1" repeatInterval="60000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
            <quartz:event-generator-job />
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                <scripting:text><![CDATA[return '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="us-ascii"/></head><body><p>An HTML paragraph</p></body></html>']]></scripting:text>
            </scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
        <string-to-byte-array-transformer mimeType="text/html" doc:name="String to Byte Array" />
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="mail.abc.com" to="dharrington@abc.com" from="rufus@abc.com" subject="Why no markup?"
            responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="AsnEmail" mimeType="text/html" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to set the contentType on the connector:

```
<smtp:connector name="smtp"
        validateConnections="true" contentType="text/html"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the previous comment, graphically, it is enough to make the configuration of the image if you can not apply it by code

[image: Configuration via GUI]