# Send HTML response as mail in mule

Tags: smtp, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have tried a POC which return a HTML response.

I need to send the HTML response in a mail using smtp

In mail, I had received it as "org.mule.transport.http.HttpResponse@47b6ae6f"

Please find the SMTP configuration below:

```
<smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail" contentType="text/html" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail"/>
<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="${smtp_host}" port="${smtp_port}" user="${email_username}" password="${email_password}" to="${email_toaddress}" from="${email_fromaddress}" subject="${email_subject}" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="Gmail" doc:name="SMTP" mimeType="text/html"/>
```

In Java class:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
..........
html = builder.toString();
return html;
```

Comment: That is not enough data to help you. What does the flow look like? How are you calling that java code?

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use an HTML file with the Parse Template transformer,
that will work.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/parse-template-reference

Example:

https://www.appnovation.com/blog/mule-esb-using-static-templates-produce-dynamic-content

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer **Velocity** template to get it in a well designed HTML format

Reference :- [Sending formatted mails with Mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178799/sending-formatted-mails-with-mule)

https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html

Or you can also **Groovy** for a easy way:-
[I cannot get Mule to send an HTML formatted email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535806/i-cannot-get-mule-to-send-an-html-formatted-email)

Answer (score 0):

In Java class:

Using onCall ,

```
created HashMap<String, JSONArray> hDetails= new HashMap<String, JSONArray>();
String html="No data to send"
JSONArray details = new JSONArray();
...
hDetails.put(id, details);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
builder.append("<html lang=\"en\">");
builder.append("<head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;th, td {padding: 5px;} </style></head>");
builder.append("</html>");
.....

html = builder.toString();
return html;
```

I need the table to be in the mail with the details.